# Read scrapy json export into python

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I'm exporting **scraped** data with scrapy with the build command:

```
scrapy crawl quotes_spider.py -o quotes.json -t json
```

But the export file comes like this:

```
    [{
    "author": "Jane Austen",
    "text": "\u201cThe person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.\u201d"
},
{
    "author": "Groucho Marx",
    "text": "\u201cOutside of a dog, a book is man's best friend. Inside of a dog it's too dark to read.\u201d"
},
{
    "author": "Steve Martin",
    "text": "\u201cA day without sunshine is like, you know, night.\u201d"
},
...]
```

The file export comes with a bracket, as a list of dicts.

I'am trying to open this with the json module in python but with no success.

How can I open this file in python as a dict like format?

Comment: That should open with the `json` module no problem; what have you tried and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: The json.load() give this error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: you should do `json.load(open("data.json"))`

Comment: So what is on line 1 column 1?

Comment: thanks for the answers, I turns out that the file I was trying to parse had some errors.